# java 8 stream interference versus non-interference

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I understand why the following code is ok. Because the collection is being modified before calling the terminal operation.

```
List<String> wordList = ...;
Stream<String> words = wordList.stream();
wordList.add("END"); // Ok
long n = words.distinct().count();
```

But why is this code is not ok?

```
Stream<String> words = wordList.stream();
words.forEach(s -> if (s.length() < 12) wordList.remove(s)); // Error—interference
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Stream.forEach()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) is a terminal operation, and the underlying wordList collection is modified after the terminal has been started/called.

Comment: Thx. I didn't know it was a terminal op.

Answer (score 5):

[Joachim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24842046/1441122) is correct, +1.

You didn't ask specifically, but for the benefit of other readers, here are a couple techniques for rewriting the program a different way, avoiding stream interference problems.

If you want to mutate the list in-place, you can do so with a new default method on `List` instead of using streams:

```
wordList.removeIf(s -> s.length() < 12);
```

If you want to leave the original list intact but create a modified copy, you can use a stream and a collector to do that:

```
List<String> newList = wordList.stream()
    .filter(s -> s.length() >= 12)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that I had to invert the sense of the condition, since `filter` takes a predicate that *keeps* values in the stream if the condition is true.